# Failed to refresh Gradle project using Android Studio 0.4.0 and Gradle 1.9

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I've just updated Android Studio to version 0.4.0 and followed steps according to release notes here: http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio040released

After updating Gradle 1.8 to Gradle 1.9 I still get this error:
[image]

My graddle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties looks like this:

```
#Thu Dec 19 14:03:48 CET 2013
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.9-all.zip
```

It seems that Gradle has problem with brand new buildConfigField parameter:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        buildConfigField 'String' 'API_VERSION' '"api_test"'
    }
}
```

Here is a log from Gradle console:

[image]

Comment: If you click on the link in the error to fix your wrapper it still doesn't work? Any chance you're editing the wrong gradle-wrapper.properties file?

Comment: After I click on link to fix an error, my gradle-wrapper.properties is updated to the form I posted in my question and end error message is shown again.

Comment: After refreshing, can you try doing a build and pasting into your question the output you get in the Gradle console window? I think you may be running into https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63902 but I want to confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, it works fine in Android studio 0.4.2. I just needed to to change apostrophes to parenthesis and back:

```
buildConfigField 'String' 'API_VERSION' '"api_test"'
```

to

```
buildConfigField "String" "API_VERSION" "\"api_test\""
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try changing the path in the bash_profile to point to gradle 1.9? I have noticed that just changing the distributionURL on the gradle wrapper file doesn't work most of the time. Gradle is still half baked with android studio.

Update:
Since you are using android studio 0.4.0 itrequires gradle plugin 0.7.0 and gradle-wrapper 1.9.

Change your build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
    }
}
```

Comment: Changing the path in bash_profile shouldn't affect the wrapper. Gradle doesn't need to be in your shell path at all if you're using the wrapper. There has to be something else going wrong in your setup.

Comment: My ~/.bash_profile has been always empty. Gradle version is set to gradle:0.7.+ in both main project and included library.

Comment: In my experience with android studio/gradle, the distribution URL never worked for me even if i used the default wrapper. I always had to point the studio to a gradle version